# Maintaining state in MVC 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I am simply devloping entry form using mvc 3. I have many text boxes,radio button, lables. so while post back data from view to controller it loses entered data. how to retain this for all postbacks? is there any mvc mechanisam avialable by default? which means by enabling some properties do we command mvc  to handle state by itself?

i am not interested to send viewdata object  to view. except that what is default mechanism availble in mvc3?

## Update:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>

            @Html.TextBox("txtTitle")
@Html.CheckBox("chkOption")
        </td>
        <td>               
            @Html.TextBox("txtDetails")
@Html.DropDownList("drpList")
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" value="Cancel" name="action" />
            <input type="submit" value="Create" name="action" />

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
}
```

How to maintain state for entered and selected value for all post backs?

Comment: Could you update your question with some of the code you are trying? e.g. the Controller(s) and View? Just the relative parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to create a `Model` and use the `@Html.TextBoxFor()`, `@Html.CheckBoxFor()` and `@Html.DropdownListFor()` methods instead, on the properties of your model.

You would then have a similarly named action method, decorated with a `[HttpPost]` attribute and the model as a parameter.  You will then be able to perform validation on attempted form submissions and process the model if the form state is valid.

I'd look into researching strongly typed views, models and maybe go through a few online tutorials.

The link included below seems a good tutorial, it's a few pages long, but should go through everything you need to get started.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/cs/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-3

Comment: but i should not tightly coupled with any model. so without using model how to maintain state across postbacks?

Comment: Think of it as a view model, an object graph with the sole purpose of serving and binding a view with the data it requires.  This is completely fine in MVC design and wouldn't influence any pre-existing domain models/entities you might have.  Otherwise maybe you should go with using the `Session`, you'd be missing out on a lot of MVC goodness though.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx) to persist state across multiple postbacks.